# Experience Manager and multi value (embedded) fields

Tags: 2011, experience-manager, dd4t, 2011-sp1

I can't seem to find a way to enable the Experience Manager to add an extra embedded fieldset, or even an extra line of text for a multi-value field.

Is this even possible, or does the content editor have to open the component in form view in order to "advanced" edit/create the component?

Comment: Multi-value embedded fields are not supported in Experience Manager for 2011 SP1. (It is in 2013)

Comment: So this: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/task_A653FB9B7D4247578604A3397CCEC2E0 can only be used in combination with Tridion 2013?

Comment: Yes, that's one of the biggest changes to XPM in 2013 SP1.

Comment: Managing multi-value fields (the same field repeated) was possible in Tridion 2011 (UI Update), whereas the markup for multi-value *embedded* fields (set of fields from an Embeddable Schema) was added in 2013 SP1.

Comment: Make it an answer, so I can mark it as the right answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quote Alvin Reyes':

> "Managing multi-value fields (the same field repeated) was
>   possible in Tridion 2011 (UI Update), whereas the markup for
>   multi-value embedded fields (set of fields from an Embeddable Schema)
>   was added in 2013 SP1."